# Boost C++ regex - how to return all matches

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have and string `"SolutionAN  ANANANA SolutionBN"` I want to return all string which start with `Solution` and end with `N`.

While using regex `boost::regex regex("Solu(.*)N");`
I am getting output as `SolutionAN  ANANANA SolutionBN`.

While I want to get out as `SolutionAN`   and `SolutionBN`. I am new to regex in boost any help will be appreciated.
Snippet if code I am using

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int ac,char* av[])
{
    std::string strTotal("SolutionAN ANANANA SolutionBN");
    boost::regex regex("Solu(.*)N");

    boost::sregex_token_iterator iter(strTotal.begin(), strTotal.end(), regex, 0);
    boost::sregex_token_iterator end;

    for( ; iter != end; ++iter ) {
           std::cout<<*iter<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `*` is greedy. Change to using the non-greedy version (note the `?`):

```
int main(int ac,char* av[])
{
    std::string strTotal("SolutionAN ANANANA SolutionBN");
    boost::regex regex("Solu(.*?)N");

    boost::sregex_token_iterator iter(strTotal.begin(), strTotal.end(), regex, 0);
    boost::sregex_token_iterator end;

    for( ; iter != end; ++iter ) {
           std::cout<<*iter<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot, I have one additional doubt in regex suppose I have input SolutionAN ANANANA SolutionBN abc abc Solution . I want to get all string which start with SOlu and end where next Solu  get started for example
Input :SolutionAN ANANANA SolutionBN abc abc Solution
Output : 3 different string
 SolutionAN ANANANA    
 SolutionBN abc abc
 Solution

Comment: What if I need to iterate and get only a capture group (not the whole matched pattern) ?